# How to make LinearLayout clickable?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner on Android Studio.
I would like to make my LinearLayout clickable, I have been trying this since yesterday but I still can not fix it. Below the onClick method for my layout in MainActivity class. It does not work at all, I tried everything you could imagine.
[image]

Below the layout.
[image]

Comment: 1. Always paste code here, not screenshots. 2. You don't seem to add notePreview to any layout

Comment: @Gardener Yes, I tried it.

Comment: @cmak Sorry, I am a beginner in Stack Overflow. And what do you mean by adding a layout to notePreview?

Comment: After you inflate the view, do you ever add it to the parent view? If not, that layout would not be shown anywhere. If you want that to just be a part of the main layout you would usually just add/include it in `activity_main.xml` instead of inflating it manually. You need to edit your question to show the full `onCreate` method (as text, not an image) and the content of the relevant XML files (activity_main.xml and note_preview.xml at least).

Comment: Also, when you ask a question "it does not work at all" is not helpful - you need to be very specific and tell people what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.